# TextClock format12 is wrong on device

Tags: android

I use TextClock in xml, try launch in simulation is correct:

[image: I Want this]

But I try to device (Samsung s20)It's show this:

[image: It Show this]

Here it my code `

```
                    <TextClock
                        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:format12Hour="dd MMM yyyy"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/tvTime"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvTime"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTime"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />

<TextClock
                        android:id="@+id/tvTime"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:format12Hour="hh:mm:ss"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textSize="45dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: It sounds like your device is set to display 24 hour format. While your emulator is set to show 12 hour format. Try setting the 24hour format option too.

Comment: @IAmGroot ThankYou ,I set 24 format It's work